# Sequelize OR with null

Tags: sql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am trying to use Sequelize to generate a (semi) complex conditional.

The SQL I am trying to generate is:

```
SELECT * FROM Tasks
WHERE completedDate IS NULL OR completedDate < CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

So I am using the Sequelize command:

```
Task.findAll({
  where: {
    completedDate: null
  },
  $or: [
    {
      completedDate: {
        $lt: new Date()
      }
    }
  ]
});
```

However it returns 0 rows. Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe that the Sequelize `$or` requires both conditions to be in the same block. Try something like this:

```
Task.findAll({
    completedDate: {
       $or: {
            $eq: null,
            $lt: new Date()
       }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

For those using the new format, this also worked for me.

```
const userSubscription = await db.Task.findOne({
  where: {
    completedAt: {
      [db.Sequelize.Op.or]: {
        [db.Sequelize.Op.eq]: null,
        [db.Sequelize.Op.lte]: new Date (),
      },
    }
  },
});
```